# Does the CM frame imply zero angular momentum in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

There's something that has bugged me for a while. The cm of mass frame does not imply zero angular momentum in QM right? People usually assume this but it makes no sense. Take the spinless Hydrogen atom as an example. The $l=0$ orbital has zero angular momentum. The orbital's shape is spheric. Now, the zero linear momentum state's wavefunction is
$$
\psi(\vec{r})=Ce^{i0\vec{r}}=C
$$
a constant. This can never give rise to the spheric orbital of the $l=0$ case. Furthermore, momentum states are not square integrable, as oppossed to physical states, so they can never be the same, right?

Comment: This isn't really any different from the situation in classical mechanics. A single particle with $0$ linear momentum also has $0$ orbital angular momentum. If, however, you have multiple particle you can choose a centre of mass/relative position coordinate system. You can then choose a reference frame such that the conjugate momentum of the centre of mas position is 0, but still have interesting structure (including non-zero angular momentum) in the relative position coordinate.

Comment: The single particle can't be rotating about some axis?